# Scalars in tensor notation

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

I know that usually the number of indices on a tensor indicates it’s rank, so how do you represent a scalar/rank zero tensor. I’ve had trouble making this work and it seems at times like there’s ambiguity between scalars and vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: the number of indices indicates the rank, so a scalar has no indices and hence a single component (cf. $n$ components of a vector).